# Running our own Popcorntime?

Tags: javascript, json, git

I'm trying to run a privately compiled popcorntime app (I know it's been shutdown, that's the reason I wanna do it **privately**).

However it doesn't load, just hangs with the loading icon spinning.

[Here](https://github.com/popcorn-time/popcorn-app) is the project git hub;

Here is what I found in popcorn-app-master\js\frontend\player.js:

```
    flix.server.on('listening', function () {
      var href = 'http://127.0.0.1:' + flix.server.address().port + '/';
```

Not sure if it's related.

How can I make this work?

**EDIT:** The problem is the API, which doesn't exist anymore.

\js\frontend\providers\torrents.js

line 3:

```
var url = 'http://subapi.com/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you founded any alternatives? So far I could see, this popular rank can be created using some search apis like google. Another option is to create some github project that do what the subapi.com used to do. For now, I will try to make the popcorn time work without it. If I have some succeed you will know into the github.

If someone have some example of json received from the subapi.com, that will help a lot.